# Is dependeny injection possible when using the new operator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

Actually I want to implement some sort of strategy pattern. More precisely, I want to decide on runtime which class to instanciate.

Of course this is pretty simple.

```
if(...) {
this.service = new ServiceA();
} else {
this.service = new ServiceB();
}
```

But what if ServiceA and ServiceB use dependency injection in their classes? Do I have to pass those instances or is there a nicer way to let nest inject them automatically?

Comment: No, you can't create the dependency and inject it. Though Kim has a good option for you below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject both services and then assign them to your variable dynamically:

```
service: Service;
constructor(private serviceA: ServiceA, private serviceB: ServiceB) {}

dynamicMethod() {
  if (...) {
    this.service = this.serviceA;
  } else {
    this.service = this.serviceB;
  }
}
```

---

If the condition can be evaluated on startup (e.g. environment variabels) you can use a [custom provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#factory-providers-usefactory) instead.